# c# call for values by linq to xml

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm learning about reading and retrieving data from XML files. I have xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="IK.xsl"?>
<IK>
    <Folders>
        <Folder>
            <name>nameA</name>
            <info>nazwa pierwsza</info>
            <komps>
               <K1 id="1">komp1</K1>
               <K1 id="2">komp2</K1>
               <K1 id="3">komp3</K1>
               <K1 id="4">komp4</K1>
               <K1 id="5">komp5</K1>
            </komps
        </Folder>
        <Folder>
            <name>nameB</name>
            <info>nazwa druga</info>
            <komps>
               <K1 id="1">komp1</K1>
               <K1 id="2">komp2</K1>
               <K1 id="3">komp3</K1>
               <K1 id="4">komp4</K1>
               <K1 id="5">komp5</K1>
            </komps
        </Folder>
        <Folder>
            <name>nameC</name>
            <info>nazwa trzecia</info>
            <komps>
               <K1 id="1">komp1</K1>
               <K1 id="2">komp2</K1>
               <K1 id="3">komp3</K1>
               <K1 id="4">komp4</K1>
               <K1 id="5">komp5</K1>
            </komps 
        </Folder>

    </Folders>
</IK>
```

and class

```
public class Foldery
{
    public Folder folder { get; set; }
}

public class Folder
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string info { get; set; }
    public Komps[] komps { get; set; }
        }

        public class Komps
        {
            public string K1 { get; set; }
        }
}
```

I want to put all Folders values into a list Folder objects using linq to xml?
All the example which i found is for first level nodes and I don't know how to get to deeper level of xml and retrieve data from.

What about "komps" values which are another list of strings??

Comment: If you want to retrieve deeper levels of your XML file you need to add that to your Class that you use for Deserializing. For Example Make a Folder Component that has a List of Folders which in itself has a name and a info component.

Comment: @MathewHD
I corrected my class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manage to get to data in komps using loops and

```
var komps = item.Descendants("Folder").Descendants("komps").Descendants("K1");
```

Answer (score 3):

The `XDocument` class has a method called [Descendants](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.descendants?view=net-5.0#System_Xml_Linq_XContainer_Descendants_System_Xml_Linq_XName_). It has an overload where you can provide an `XName` as a filter criteria for elements. Fortunately there is an implicit cast operator between `string` and `XName`.

So, in order to retrieve the `Folder` elements into a List you can use the following code:

```cs
//Retrieve and load the xml
using var fs = File.OpenRead("Sample.xml");
var reader = new StreamReader(fs);
var rawXml = reader.ReadToEnd();

//Parse the xml
var document = XDocument.Parse(rawXml);
var folders = document.Descendants("Folder")
    .Select(element => new Folder
    {
        Name = element.Element("name")?.Value,
        Info = element.Element("info")?.Value,
    }).ToList();
```

---

**UPDATE**: Providing an alternative

You can also filter for the `Folders` element and ask for its child nodes:

```cs
document.Descendants("Folders").Elements()
```

Comment: It's working but i have only 5 Folder objects in xml but folders list gets 16 elements, 11 of them nulls.

Comment: What happened when "Folder" will be used in other part of xml, I mean this one is in Folders, what if there will be another second node Folder in other node?

Comment: @simoNPL I've used that xml which was provided in the question. I've run the code several times and the `folders` collection always contains only 5 `Folder` object instances.

Comment: @simoNPL You can use `document.Descendants("Folders").Elements()` as an alternative. Here we locate first the `Folders` element and then we ask for its child elements.

Comment: Maybe because I cut rest of the xml but there where only other nods in the rest of xml.
But in other nodes there where node Foldery but there weren't nodes Folder